Is the sequence of event clear without past perfect?

I bought your first LP and I liked it
very much. I thought you split up as I did not hear about you for a long time,  until I saw on a bandcamp that you have released two other singles.

I think past simple is ok here for split up and did not hear as the sequence of events is clear.
Am I right?

Simple past is OK but a bit clunky.  That's a place where the past perfect (I thought you had split up) would do double duty, identifying the time sequence but also underscoring the fact that you were mistaken.  did not hear is fine.

"two other singles".

It kind of depends on how little a band can do and still be significant (the subject of discussion). It's possible they released their first LP before splitting or after reforming. Even though most bands split without releasing an LP, the intended meaning is more likely "I heard their first album and liked it, then they split and I didn't think about them, but sometime after that they reunited and recorded 2 more singles." That's a plausible sequence of events. It's also possible they released the singles before splitting, but that would be a bit odd in the context (how old is Bandcamp?).

@TimR I don't find it clunky at all. We don't use past perfect very much in the US.

I think the sequence is pretty clear: You bought their first LP. Then you didn't hear about them for a while, and concluded that they split up. Then you saw two new singles on Bandcamp, and realized that they're still together (or have reunited).
